# how to delete file in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have dynamic listing page. From that I want to `delete` file from server using joomla2.5. I try with the following code:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$path = JPath::clean($path);
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the folder:

```
JFolder::delete(JPATH_ROOT.DS.'modules'.DS.'mod_footer');
```

To delete the File:

```
JFile::delete(JPATH_ROOT.DS.'modules'.DS.'mod_footer'.DS.'mod_footer.php');
```